# LibreOffice global menu not working (ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: 13.04, libreoffice, hud

There is a BUG on ubuntu 13.04 with libreoffice 4, the global menu and HUF do not work correctly.

I use ubuntu 13.04 (I intalled the BETA 2, a week before the final release)

[image: Here is the screenshot of the bug]

Comment: If this is a **bug** report it, bugs are off-topic here.

Comment: I need to know if I'm the only one who has this "bug"

Comment: Please see [this](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=libreoffice+hud), no you're not the only one.

Comment: @Uri Herrera: This is the first result on Google for "LibreOffice Ubuntu 13.04 HUD". I also am wondering if this is a bug, or if the HUD simply is not meant to work for LibreOffice on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: It's a bug, found the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1045353 Go mark yourself as affected.